# A tikz plot with date x-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am working on a tikz plot that depicts a time series with data spanning for about 20 years. Below is my simple latex code and the plot itself is at the bottom. My questions, which I need to resolve, are:

1. How to make the x-axis labels having 12-month interval instead of 1-month (every data point)?
2. How to add a red vertical line indicating an event as of Feb 24, 2022?
3. How to add a gray colored rectangle, indicating an area from Feb 24, 2022 thru Feb 27, 2024?

I will be grateful very much for your helpful insights!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm,compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.dateplot}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
Date,Ind1,Ind2,Ind3,Ind4
2021-01-01,64,34,2,30
2021-02-01,65,34,2,31
2021-03-01,63,35,2,28
2021-04-01,65,33,2,32
2021-05-01,67,32,2,35
2021-06-01,66,32,2,34
2021-07-01,64,35,1,29
2021-08-01,61,37,2,24
2021-09-01,64,34,2,30
2021-10-01,67,33,1,34
2021-11-01,63,35,2,28
2021-12-01,65,34,1,31
2022-01-01,69,29,2,40
2022-02-01,71,27,1,44
2022-03-01,83,15,2,68
2022-04-01,82,17,1,65
2022-05-01,83,15,2,68
2022-06-01,83,16,1,67
2022-07-01,83,15,2,68
2022-08-01,83,15,2,68
2022-09-01,77,21,2,56
2022-10-01,79,19,2,60
2022-11-01,79,18,3,61
2022-12-01,81,17,2,64
2023-01-01,82,16,2,66
2023-02-01,83,14,2,69
2023-03-01,82,15,3,67
2023-04-01,83,14,3,69
2023-05-01,82,15,2,67
2023-06-01,81,16,3,65
2023-07-01,82,15,3,67
2023-08-01,80,16,4,64
2023-09-01,80,17,3,63
2023-10-01,82,15,3,67
2023-11-01,85,13,2,72
2023-12-01,83,14,3,69
2024-01-01,85,12,2,73
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
date coordinates in=x,
xtick=data,
xticklabel style={rotate=90,anchor=near xticklabel},
xticklabel=\month.\year, % required, example: Jan-24
xtick distance=1000,
title={}, xlabel={},
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
extra y tick style={grid=major, tick label style={xshift=-1cm}},
ylabel={},
date ZERO=2009-08-18,% <- improves precision!
]
\addplot[black] table[col sep=comma,x=Date,y=Ind1] {data.txt};
\addplot[blue]  table[col sep=comma,x=Date,y=Ind4] {data.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it.

1. Say which ticks you want, where you have already used the `dateplot` lib, and which make statement `xtick=data,` kind of obsolete:

```
...
        date ZERO=2009-08-18,% <- improves precision!
        % ~~~ which major ticks to show ~~~
        xtick={2021-01-01, 2022-01-01, 2023-01-01, 2024-01-01},
        % ~~~ put 11 for months, or 3 for quarters in between ~~~
        minor x tick num=3,
        ]
...
```

2. Use coordinates for the gray area and draw it first; i.e. specify the whole path, which could be far from being rectangular:

```
        % ~~~ gray area: draw fist ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \addplot[fill=gray!30,draw=none] coordinates {
            (2022-02-24,30)(2022-02-24,90)
            (2024-02-27,90)(2024-02-27,30)
            (2022-02-24,30)
            };
```

3. Same for the red vertical:

```
        % ~~~ red vertical ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \addplot[red] coordinates {(2022-02-24,15)(2022-02-24,100)};
```

**Suggestion**: You may also want to use annotation, see Ch. 4.17 in the manual, e.g. to indicate the red and gray dates.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm,compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.dateplot}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
Date,Ind1,Ind2,Ind3,Ind4
2021-01-01,64,34,2,30
2021-02-01,65,34,2,31
2021-03-01,63,35,2,28
2021-04-01,65,33,2,32
2021-05-01,67,32,2,35
2021-06-01,66,32,2,34
2021-07-01,64,35,1,29
2021-08-01,61,37,2,24
2021-09-01,64,34,2,30
2021-10-01,67,33,1,34
2021-11-01,63,35,2,28
2021-12-01,65,34,1,31
2022-01-01,69,29,2,40
2022-02-01,71,27,1,44
2022-03-01,83,15,2,68
2022-04-01,82,17,1,65
2022-05-01,83,15,2,68
2022-06-01,83,16,1,67
2022-07-01,83,15,2,68
2022-08-01,83,15,2,68
2022-09-01,77,21,2,56
2022-10-01,79,19,2,60
2022-11-01,79,18,3,61
2022-12-01,81,17,2,64
2023-01-01,82,16,2,66
2023-02-01,83,14,2,69
2023-03-01,82,15,3,67
2023-04-01,83,14,3,69
2023-05-01,82,15,2,67
2023-06-01,81,16,3,65
2023-07-01,82,15,3,67
2023-08-01,80,16,4,64
2023-09-01,80,17,3,63
2023-10-01,82,15,3,67
2023-11-01,85,13,2,72
2023-12-01,83,14,3,69
2024-01-01,85,12,2,73
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}\lipsum[1]

 \begin{figure}[!ht]
 \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        date coordinates in=x,
        xtick=data,
        xticklabel style={rotate=90,anchor=near xticklabel},
        xticklabel={\month.\year}, % required, example: Jan-24
        xtick distance=1000,
        title={}, xlabel={},
        y tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
        extra y tick style={grid=major, 
                            tick label style={xshift=-1cm}},
        ylabel={},
        date ZERO=2009-08-18,% <- improves precision!
        % ~~~ which major ticks to show ~~~
        xtick={2021-01-01, 2022-01-01, 2023-01-01, 2024-01-01},
        % ~~~ put 11 for months, or 3 for quarters in between ~~~
        minor x tick num=3,
        ]
        
        % ~~~ gray area: draw fist ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \addplot[fill=gray!30,draw=none] coordinates {
            (2022-02-24,30)(2022-02-24,90)
            (2024-02-27,90)(2024-02-27,30)
            (2022-02-24,30)
            };
        
        % ~~~ your data ~~~~~~~~~~~
        \addplot[black] table[col sep=comma,x=Date,y=Ind1] {data.txt};
        \addplot[blue]  table[col sep=comma,x=Date,y=Ind4] {data.txt};

        % ~~~ red vertical ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \addplot[red] coordinates {(2022-02-24,15)(2022-02-24,100)};
        
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{Caption}
 \label{fig:enter-label}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```